# Spring Integration - Error Channel - Getting the original message

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Is there any way to get the original message in the error channel. All I am able to get the Message of Exception type. I need to get the original message and log it.

Highly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ErrorMessage` payload is a `MessagingException`.

The exception has two properties `cause` and `failedMessage` which is the message at the time of the failure.

Comment: Its working..Thank u so much for the help!!!
Just a clarification - I am using the error channel to log the message that was discarded due to the inbound queue full and all worker threads are busy. Is there any other way to get the discarded messages (ex: Using task rejecection handler) instead of using error channel

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; perhaps ask another question showing more details/configuration etc.